# Using MIDI to USB cable to get information in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, usb, midi

I recently started developing a program using the `k8062d.dll` for the Velleman VM116.
My mixing table is a SGM studio 12 from which I have a MIDI to USB cable going into my laptop. I am using `Microsoft Visual Basic 2010` to code my program. Now, what I need is when changing a slide on my mixing table it sends an signal through the MIDI cable, but I can't seem to find how I would receive this information in Visual Basic.

Anyone who knows what to do?

Thanks,

Merijn

Comment: There's nothing special about MIDI over USB... it's exposed as a regular MIDI device to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET does not have built-in MIDI support.

You need to access the raw [Win32 MIDI API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712733.aspx) using P/Invoke.

Alternatively, use [some library that already does this](http://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/).

Comment: Well ok, I'm trying to use the `MIDI.NET`, which I added to my project.. But now what? I have no idea on how to connect with it as I can't seem to find it on the internet and the official `midi-dot-net` example doesn't work when downloaded (no code found)

Comment: See the [simple examples](http://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/wiki/SimpleExamples).

Answer (score 3):

There are other libraries you can use as well. Like [MIDI.NET](http://midinet.codeplex.com), [The C# Midi Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6228/C-MIDI-Toolkit) and perhaps [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com). Search for managed Midi libraries and pick one that suits you most.